# c# ((DateTime)object) vs Datetime.Parse

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, date-conversion

I'm new to c#.

I've an SQLite table containing  "marketDate" field (datatype **Date**) and I'm using SQLiteDataReader.

I need to build a string this way: **MONDAY 2016-01-03**

So far I've found 2 ways of doing it:

1)

```
myString = (DateTime.Parse(reader["marketDate"].ToString())).ToString("dddd").ToUpper() + " " + (DateTime.Parse(reader["marketDate"].ToString())).ToShortDateString();
```

2)

```
myString = ((DateTime)reader["marketDate"]).ToString("dddd").ToUpper() + " " + ((DateTime)reader["marketDate"]).ToShortDateString();
```

I'd like to know which is the best way of doing it (best practice), and I'd really appreciate if someone will explain me the differences beetween the 2 approaches  **datetime.parse** and **(datetime)object)**. I couldn't find any info about the second one.

Thanks

Comment: If you know that the DB type is DateTime I would suggest casting directly like your second example. However you dont need two cast ((DateTime)reader["marketDate"]).ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd").ToUpper() would work for you.

Comment: Look at the signature, `DateTime.Parse(str)` takes a `string`, `(DateTime)obj` takes an `object` which is actually a date. If you already have a `DateTime`, such in this case, it's better to directly cast it rather than converting the `DateTime` to `string` with `ToString()` first and then parsing that back to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
DateTime.Parse(reader["marketDate"].ToString())
```

1. gets the date from the reader (`reader["marketDate"]`). The result is of type `DateTime`.
2. This DateTime is converted to a string (`.ToString()`).
3. This string is converted back to a DateTime (`DateTime.Parse(...)`).

As you can see, steps 2 and 3 are redundant and can be omitted. Which is exactly what your second code example does:

```
(DateTime)reader["marketDate"]
```

1. The date is read from the reader (`reader["marketDate"]`). This is currently of type `DateTime`, but the compiler does not know that yet (since reader's indexer returns the supertype *object*). Thus, we tell that compiler that we *know* this is a `DateTime` by explicitly casting it. This allows us to call DateTime-specific methods on it.

Since you asked about best practice: Your second example is better than the first one. However, my preferred solution would be to use [SQLiteDataReader.GetDateTime](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader~GetDateTime.html):

```
reader.GetDateTime("marketDate")
```

Comment: thanks, I will check which one is faster and use that (have tons of records)

Comment: @SupSup: If performance of that part is really that critical, you might save a few cycles by using the column index instead of the column name.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you do:

1. A conversion from a `DateTime` (boxed in an `Object`) to a `String`. For this conversion a string must be created (memory reservation) and filled, depending on the current culture settings.
2. Than that `String` is converted back to a `DateTime`. Parsing is also done based on the current culture settings.

Both operations together are a relative (to casting) long process. When both conversions are finished, the `String` is removed from memory again, since it is no longer needed. Feels a bit redundant, right?

In your second example you use a cast. A cast is a relative simple operation: It checks if the object contains the given type. If so, that object is returned, otherwise an InvalidCastException is thrown.

In both examples you repeat both operations twice. It would be faster to do it once:

```
DateTime marketDate = (DateTime)reader["marketDate"];
myString = marketDate.ToString("dddd").ToUpper() + " " + marketDate.ToShortDateString();
```

If you want to use the format "yyyy-MM-dd" explicitly (and want to disregard cultural settings), you could use:

```
DateTime marketDate = (DateTime)reader["marketDate"];
myString = marketDate.ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd").ToUpper();
```

Since this is now one operation, your can do this:

```
myString = ((DateTime)reader["marketDate"]).ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd").ToUpper();
```

Comment: thanks, U're right I was doing the same casting twice... just out of curiosity:  would it be really doing twice the work  or the compiler whould have optimized that?

Comment: The compiler will not optimize it. This is because the call to retrieve the object reader["marketDate"] is nothing more than a method call. And a call to a method can result in different results every time.

Answer (score 1):

As the `marketDate` filed of type `Date` you can cast it to `DateTime`. Then get its representation in appropriate way use this:

```
((DateTime)reader["marketDate"]).ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd").ToUpper();
```

Comment: @JonSkeet Best option would be to use Noda Time for DateTime ;)

Comment: `ToShortDateString` does not always return the format "yyyy-MM-dd". It depends on the current culture which is ignore in your code.

Comment: @MartinMulder Do you see usage of `ToShortDateString` in my answer? Read OP closer. What is the primary goal of OP? I think it is `I need to build a string this way: MONDAY 2016-01-03`

Answer (score 1):

### Breakdown

Wanted to start with a breakdown of what is going on here to help give you a better understanding of...what is going on here ( should think of a better way to phrase that ).

#### DateTime.Parse (for this situation not the right way)

In the first example the first thing getting executed that we care about is :

```
reader["marketDate"].ToString()
```

So read the data in as a string, awesome, to make our lives easier lets assign it to a variable, and do the rest

```
var str = reader["marketDate"].ToString();
var myStr = myString = 
                       (DateTime.Parse(str)).ToString("dddd").ToUpper() + " " 
                                + (DateTime.Parse(str)).ToShortDateString();
```

So here, if you see what is going on here, in this

1. Getting Value of column `marketDate` from db table
2. Calling to String on the Date object, which makes a string representation of the Date value
3. Using Parse on the string that we created from the Date object
4. Calling ToString again to get the formatted string you need

So, you're doing **double work** here, you are converting back and forth between data types, which in general is a no-no.

#### ((DateTime)object) (Correct way for this situation)

The first thing that is happening is...

```
(DateTime)reader["marketDate"]
```

Here you are taking the value you have been given for that row for the column `marketDate` and **Casting** (which is essentially changing the type from one type to another at least in C# as the cast mechanism can be overridden)

Now if we look at the expression with variables

```
var dt = (DateTime)reader["marketDate"];
var myString = dt.ToString("dddd").ToUpper() + " " + marketDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Here we are **not** yo-yoing between different types, which is why it makes sense that this is the best answer.